# Algorithm: Permutations & Signature

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, programming, algorithm, vector-calculus

**Theoretical side**

*Simple example:* If I have two sets $A_1=\{1,3\}  ,A_2=\{2,3\}$

and `Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]`= $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 1 & 3 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 & 3 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

**Solution steps**

**1-** Choose the rows whose sets $A_1=\{1,3\}  ,A_2=\{2,3\}$ are partial and then count the number of rows
$D_2=\{1,3,2\},\{3,1,2\},\{2,3,1\},\{3,2,1\}$

$S_2=Count[D_2]/Count[Permutations[\{1, 2, 3\}]]=4/6$

**2-** Delete $D_2$ from $Permutations[\{1, 2, 3\}]$  and choose from the triple order whose sets $A_1=\{1,3\}  ,A_2=\{2,3\}$ are partial and then count the number of rows

$D_3=\{1,2,3\},\{2,1,3\}$

$S_3=Count[D_3]/Count[Permutations[\{1, 2, 3\}]]=2/6$

**How can you write code that achieves this algorithm and maintains globality?**

###########

#Edit

sets are partial:The group is contained within the second order

**$D_2$**:Such that

$A_1=\{1,3\}\subset\{1,3,-\}$ take $\{1,3,-\}$
$A_1=\{1,3\}\subset\{3,1,-\}$ take $\{3,1,-\}$
$A_2=\{2,3\}\subset\{2,3,-\}$ take $\{1,3,-\}$
$A_2=\{2,3\}\subset\{3,2,-\}$ take $\{3,1,-\}$

Then; We obtain
$$D_2=\{1,3,2\},\{3,1,2\},\{2,3,1\},\{3,2,1\}$$

**$D_3$**:Such that

$A_1=\{1,3\}\subset\{1,2,3\}$ take $\{1,2,3\}$
$A_1=\{2,3\}\subset\{2,1,3\}$ take $\{2,1,3\}$

Then; We obtain
$$D_3=\{1,2,3\},\{2,1,3\}$$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "sets are partial".

Comment: @CarlWoll sets are partial: The set is contained within the second order

**$D_2$**;

$A_1=\{1,3\}\subset\{1,3,-\}$ 
or $A_1=\{1,3\}\subset\{3,1,-\}$

And, The set is contained within the thirds order

**$D_3$**;

$A_1=\{1,3\}\subset\{1,2,3\}$